# How to access premises AD in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have implemented one MVC application and in that application we did authentication using `windows Active Directory` and we have implemented `Single Sign On` in this application.

Now I want to deploy that application in Azure.
So, How to access premises AD in Azure?

Comment: Have you tried Googling your question? This is the first link that comes up: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not be accessible by default.
You need to set up the private network (VPN) between your MVC app and local network. For that, [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/) may be helpful.
Next, you should be able to query your on-premise AD once they will be in the same context. However, i am not very sure that it will be OK to query your AD directly. Try to use [AD FS way](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-adfs/) - it may be more suitable for the task. If not, the traditional ways of querying the AD from MVC app should work (ex.: [that](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/)).